# Is there a way to scaffold a Stored Proc in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following:

```
TableA
TableAToB
TableB
TableBToC
TableC
```

End result is, I want to get one column of a subset of rows from TableC, but to get to that, I need to start with a where on TableA, join to AToB, join to B, join to BToC, etc.

Am I supposed to scaffold those 5 tables with navigation properties and use where / include? Or is there a way to use a SP?

Comment: Yes you can use SPs, but it's not clear to me what you'd want with them.

Comment: @GertArnold It's not? Did you even read the question? It's right there, plain as day. I am asking whether it is possible to use an SP to join the 5 tables and return the 1 column in TableC that I need or if I need to scaffold all the tables and use the navigation properties.

Comment: OK, if one way or another you have your single-valued list, say `IQueryable<string>`, what should scaffolding do with it? I guess the main question is: what are you trying to achieve in a wider sense?

Comment: @GertArnold, the scaffolding creates the context, navigation properties and model for you. SPs still seem like a lot of hand manipulation to get working where as it used to be more automated. In this particular case, I just want one column... but if I want to call a SP that returns 70 columns, that's a ton of hand work right now it seems.

Comment: There is currently no way to scaffold stored procedures in EF Core. As to the rest of your question, I'm unclear how that relates to the title of the post. It's not plain as day to me.

Comment: According to my knowledge, EF Core doesn't have an UI wizard or something to generate c# code from existing database yet. I have an code generation engine but it's not released as nuget package yet, do you want to test it ?